# TextView not getting updated in view pager using countdown timer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I am using a View Pager containing Image and TextView as Item. The layout of the View Pager I have shown below. I want the TextView to appear above the image only after 5 seconds. And when user slides the screen then again it should take 5 seconds for the textview to appear on that particular position. I am using Countdown Timer to make TextView appear over the Image after 5 seconds.

Problem : The problem is the TextView is getting visible on the adjacent page of the ViewPager. For Example, suppose I am at position 0, then the textview should appear at position 0 over the image after 5 seconds but the Text View is appearing at position 1 of the ViewPager instead of appearing at position 0.

Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFashion"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/kurti_1_1"

    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price : "
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/pricetextView" />


</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Adapter Class

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_horizontal_viewpager, container,
            false);

    // Locate the ImageView in list_item_horizontal_viewpagerpager.xml
    mImageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFashion);

    priceText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pricetextView); 

    priceText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    price = position + 10; // DUMMY in value


    if(cdt != null) {

        cdt.cancel();
        cdt = null;
    }

    cdt = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            Log.d("CountDOunTimer" , + millisUntilFinished/1000 + "");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hello finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("CountDOunTimer" ,   "on Finish ");

            priceText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            priceText.setText("" + String.valueOf(price));


        }
    }.start();

    // Add list_item_horizontal_viewpagerpager.xml to ViewPager .
    container.addView(itemView);


    return itemView;
}
```

Comment: `onTick` method is executing or not?

Comment: yes..onTick method is getting executed but it is updating the TextView of the Next Page ... i.e position 1 instead of updating the value at position 0

Comment: @Sir: your question is not clear plz explain more